# How can I feed a homemade IControllerActivator to DefautlControllerFactory in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

So how/where in my MVC4 app can I register an instance of IControllerActivator so that it is fed to the DefaultControllerFactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just to need to pass it as an argument to the `ControllerFactory`.

For example:

```
IControllerActivator myHomeMadeControllerActivator = new MyHomeMadeControllerActivator();
```

Then:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new DefaultControllerFactory(myOwnControllerActivator));
```